# Error de instalación: npm ERR! network Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/scheduler: aborted

Tags: reactjs, npm

Quiero hacer un Dashboard con React. Ya tengo la parte de HTML y CSS lista, solo me falta montarlo en React, y al utilizar `npx create-react-app myapp` me sale el siguiente error:

> npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
>
> npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
>
> npm ERR! network Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/scheduler: aborted
>
> npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
>
> npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
>
> npm ERR! network
>
> npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
>
> npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\CESAR.ROJAS\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-06-22T17_48_38_909Z-debug-0.log

Y acto seguido se aborta la instalación, ¿alguna solución? De verdad que no sé cómo solucionarlo.

PD: También utilicé `npm cache clean --force` para borrar el caché y tampoco funcionó.

Comment: prueba a actualizar la version de node de tu pc

Comment: Tengo ese mismo problema y ya no sé qué más probar para solucionarlo. Alguien sabe?